# Pros and cons of using Backbone for WordPress theming

Tags: themes, backbone

I've been noticing how Backbone seems to be the latest trend for WordPress theme development. A few data points:

- [Backbone.js and WordPress development resources](http://www.peterrknight.com/backbone-and-wordpress-resources/)
- [Theme Foundry's Collections theme](http://thethemefoundry.com/blog/backbonejs-and-collections-structure/).
- [Automattic's upcoming O2 theme](http://dentedreality.com.au/2013/08/17/o2-at-wordcamp-san-francisco/) seems to use Backbone.js also.
- [Happy Table's job posting looking for front-end developer](http://hmn.md/says/2013/09/23/seeking-front-end-developer/) requires Backbone experience.

I have done my homework and knew the general idea of what Backbone.js does. Nevertheless I don't have any experience with it. So, asking to those who have, what do you think are the pros and cons of using Backbone.js to develop WordPress themes?

Comment: I guess it would be better to not ask for _pros and cons_, but for something more specific. I'm not adding my close vote, but please rework your question. As it currently stands it will be closed as it's too broad and can't be answered in a way that you'll really get a _solution_. And an upvote, but as well a close vote. Can be reopened after narrowing it down.